# Magnetic Metallurgy: Evaluating the Structural Implications of Introducing Magnetism to Armor Components

Tags: physics

Would the implementation of magnetic properties in the metal plates, rivets, or scales of an armor compromise its structural integrity and make it more susceptible to fragility, considering factors such as potential disruptions to the material bonding, alterations in the overall composition, and the impact of magnetic forces on the armor's ability to withstand external stresses and impacts?

edit, i have a metal alloy that is used for armor making, does making that metal alloy into an artificial magnet make it more fragile? and if so are all magnets generally more fragile than non magnetic metals?

Comment: from my experience modern commercial magnets are quite fragile and break like porceilain, if it applies to all types of magnetis, that I do not know, this is why I'm asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "modern commercial magnets". *Some* permanent magnets are made of ceramic materials, and this is why they are so brittle. Others are made of metallic alloys and are much less brittle. But then the question is speaking of swords and arrows, so that when asking about armor it must refer to historical iron or steel armor; in those days they did not know how to make non-magnetic steel so that *all* armor was ferromagnetic; the point being that I don't understand what is meant by "implementation of magnetic properties".

Comment: Wouldn't it loss magnetism if struck repeatedly by a force?

Comment: @Blue - Question (which might help get some more interesting answers): Why would you want Magnetic Armour? Is there a reason from a story perspective - outside 'Magnets are cool'? And depending on your level of tech, Magnetic Armour might have issues (interferes with a Compass, interferes with digital devices etc.) - so curious as to the reason?

Comment: @TheDemonLord gimmick armor in my videogame, i just need to see if would work as armor first, story and lore about this item... maybe later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Magnetising a piece of ferrous metal will not weaken the metal.  Aside from the [magnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetism) properties of a piece of metal, nothing much changes when metal is magnetised.

However, magnetising armour steels may not be very successful, as the metals that make the best magnets are not necessarily the same as those that make the best armour.

The misconception that all magnets are fragile probably comes from [ferrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_(magnet)), which is a brittle material that makes good magnets.